# How to get information of .so file generated by their corresponding library in APK file using android studio

Tags: android, aar, lib

I have recently included few external .aar library files for some implementation and my app size increased drastically. Since i'm using proguard i want to know which library is causing increase in APK size.
Is there anyway i could see which .so file belong to which dependency/library of gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You could add [this](https://gist.github.com/medvedev/968119d7786966d9ed4442ae17aca279) gradle task inside the `project.afterEvaluate{}`
and run it with

```
$ ./gradlew depsize
```